# Android App Spinner Causing Application to Crash When Clicked

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner

I have an android app, written in java that contains, amongst other things, a spinner, shown in the layout.xml as follows:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sprDeviceType"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It is initialised in the activity class as follows:

```
public class AddDevice extends Activity
{
    private Spinner deviceTypeSpinner;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add);  //Set the layout

        populateDeviceTypeSpinner();
    }

    private void populateDeviceTypeSpinner()
    {
        String device_type_spinner[];

        device_type_spinner = new String[2];
        device_type_spinner[0] = "FTP";
        device_type_spinner[1] = "QAF";

        deviceTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sprDeviceType);

        ArrayAdapter deviceTypeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, device_type_spinner);

        deviceTypeSpinner.setAdapter(deviceTypeArrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the program, it opens the activity fine, but when I click the spinner to get the drop down items, it crashes the program, throwing a NullPointerException.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The LogCat shows:

```
08-14 14:57:02.034: D/AndroidRuntime(1612): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-14 14:57:02.034: D/AndroidRuntime(1612): CheckJNI is OFF
08-14 14:57:02.074: D/AndroidRuntime(1612): --- registering native functions ---
08-14 14:57:05.004: D/AndroidRuntime(1612): Shutting down VM
08-14 14:57:05.014: I/AndroidRuntime(1612): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-14 14:57:05.184: D/AndroidRuntime(1637): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-14 14:57:05.184: D/AndroidRuntime(1637): CheckJNI is OFF
08-14 14:57:05.224: D/AndroidRuntime(1637): --- registering native functions ---
08-14 14:57:05.524: D/AndroidRuntime(1637): Shutting down VM
08-14 14:57:05.544: I/AndroidRuntime(1637): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

Comment: posted, but it doesn't look very helpful @gtumca-MAC

Comment: i dont find Null pointer in your logcat plz post related logcat

Comment: post the logcat output with tag AndroidRuntime

Comment: edited with tag AndroidRuntime @nandeesh

Comment: Please add your LogCat in the right way. Not like this. I don't even understand what it says. Just copy the entire stack trace.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by LogCat. I am copying the text in the eclipse tag, LogCat, but evidently you mean something different. Nevermind, thanks for helping

Comment: How do you even know you have a NullPointerException? You haven't shown any indication of that from your log traces.

Comment: That's the class it throws in the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from using an array I programmed in, to using an array saved in a values xml.

```
private void populateDeviceTypeSpinner()
{
    deviceTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sprDeviceType);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> deviceTypeArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.deviceType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    deviceTypeArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    deviceTypeSpinner.setAdapter(deviceTypeArrayAdapter);
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="deviceType">
        <item >FTP</item>
        <item >QAF</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SpinnerAdapter` instead of the `ArrayAdapter`..